# Timeout after 600 Secs in hadoop

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

[mapReduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXs1G.png)

[Fail Log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH0uD.png)

[Fail Log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QJst.png)

When I run mapreduce program on large data it gives the timeout error.There is no issue in program, it executed successfully on small data. Please refer given 3 images.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Change this setting in **mapred-site.xml**

```
   <property>
    <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
    <value>1800000</value>
    </property>
```

It may helps to your problem